# Thread safe graph libraries

Tags: java, graph, thread-safety

I am looking for a good Java Graph Library which is thread safe for concurrent access.
JGraphT, JUNG, JTS are very good but again for concurrent access I will have to synchronize it externally which is becoming a pain. 
It is a pain because say If thread A have to access 50 vertices, Thread B for another 50 with the intersection of vertices being 20 vertices. Now while writing code I need to know this 20 before so that I can synchronize it accordingly.
Pl suggest

Comment: Are you sure that this even exists?

Comment: Sorry didnt get you. What exists?

Comment: Does a "thread-safe Java Graph library even exist"?

Comment: By thread-safe I mean some kind of framework where multiple threads can work on the same graph safely. Deletion, changing attributes, while calculating shortest path, making sure that no one can change any attribute's of vertices lying on that path etc.

Comment: The only remaining library I know that you didn't mention is JGraph: http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html. Could be worth a look. I haven't used it yet so I can't tell you if it is thread-safe or not in terms of graph operations.

Comment: Would you even gain much with parallelisation in your code if the datasets the threads need to work with overlap? The contention for the overlapping vertices plus the synchronisation overhead will likely kill most of the extra performance.

Comment: JGraphT is an extension of JGraph. JGraph is primarily for visualizing graphs.

Comment: Please provide more information on how you want to modify the vertices. Is the change local i.e. within the vertex or non-local i.e. affecting multiple vertices?

Comment: The change is completely local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you're looking for is impossible, because thread-safety is a property of algorithms, not a property of data structures.  Here's an example:

Let's say your graph library has a main `Graph` class with a number of methods, all of which are `synchronized`.  For example, `addVertex()`, `removeVertex()`, `addEdge()`, `removeEdge()`, etc.  Let's also say that the `Vertex` class has some useful methods like `getAdjacentEdges()`, for example, also synchronized on the containing `Graph` instance.

Now clearly because everything is synchronized, it's impossible to corrupt the data structure.  For example, you'll never have a situation where `v.getAdjacentEdges()` gives you an edge that's not actually in the graph containing vertex `v`.  The graph structure is always internally consistent thanks to its internal synchronization.

However, your algorithms operating on the graph can still easily break.  For example, let's say you write:

```
for (Edge e : v.getAdjacentEdges()) {
  g.removeEdge(e);
}
```

The call to `getAdjacentEdges()` is atomic, as is each call to `removeEdge()` in the loop, but the algorithm itself is not.  Another thread may add a new edge adjacent to `v` while this loop is running, or remove an edge, or whatever.  To be safe, you still need a way of ensuring that the loop as a whole is atomic, and the graph itself cannot provide that.

My best advice, I think, is to use JGraphT in combination with [Akka's STM](http://akka.io/docs/akka-1.0/stm-java.html) implementation (or similar), so that you can write your algorithms without needing to determine ahead of time which objects will require locking.  If you're not familiar with STM and its performance characteristics, [Wikipedia's article on the topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) does a decent job of explaining.

Comment: But there are data structures that are thread safe right? Think of ConcurrentHashMap. It is made to be used concurrently and does a good job. You cannot rule out the possibility that such a graph exists, just because it is a data structure.

Comment: -1 Thread-safety is a possible property for the implementation of data structures. Thread-safety can be more sophisticated then just adding the keyword `synchronized` to every method.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered Neo4J

Here is a snippet describing their product.

Neo4j is a high-performance, NOSQL graph database with all the features of a mature and robust database.

Comment: Thanks. I always knew about it but never used it. Will refer to it

Answer (score 1):

[JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org) now provides a [concurrent](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/graph/concurrent/package-summary.html) `AsSynchronizedGraph` graph implementation which is thread safe. In addition, JGraphT has a number of algorithmic implementations that take advantage of multiple threads. See for instance the [DeltaSteppingShortestPath](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/alg/shortestpath/DeltaSteppingShortestPath.html) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

How about letting several threads do whatever they can do and then submit there solution to one master controller that collects results and comes up with the best solution.

Comment: Nice thought but sorry will not work. This is like we are trying to get the best among the values that themselves might not be right

Comment: if synchronisation is your only concern, you can use a CopyOnWriteArrayList which is thread-safe arraylist. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

In terms of frameworks, i am not sure if there are any. But for thread-safe applications, Java 5 have many new features. You can have a look at "Atomic" data types too. They support thread-safety.

Comment: Again, i would not look thread-safety as an requirement for a framework. You can achieve thread safety with Locks, Atomic types etc.

Comment: CopyOnWrite again is not an option because it copies and writes everything again on addition. See the thing is any Java packages is futile here because externally synchronizing wont make the code scalable unless the framework itself porvides. In existing frameworks there is no way of knowing which thread is using which vertex. somehow i need to make sure that a thread when using a vertex holds it so that no one else can use it simultaneosly and this can only happen if the framework provides a design

Comment: to clear few things, synchronizing code is NOT a road block on scalable systems. Since you do not have a framework to suite your needs, you need to create one around an existing one! 

If you don't seem to control which thread is working on what vertex,  before forking a new thread and assigning vertex to it you can keep track of vertices being used by wotever thread. And since you keep track of vertices you can control as to what is happening with them.

Comment: Synchronizing is not a road block on scalable systems,but improper synchronization can get the system to its knees.I think you are still unable to get the issue with existing graph lib among JGraphT,JUNG. You cant do it manually. for ex: a thread has access to vertex A and then to vertex B. Another thread is trying to access A. Now there is no way for another thread to know if it is safe to access A unless there is internal synchronization in vertex. One can partially solve it using say read/write flags but setting different policies or designs in existing one's is a pain to set a whole system

Comment: Assuming Vertex is a class in your framework. I can create my own class that extends Vertex and name it say ThreadSafeVertex. For Basic Vertex operations override the methods and just put a call to super.realMethod() between lock.lock() and lock.unlock() calls, where lock is a Lock object inside your ThreadSafeVertex class. 

so a typical method may look like this:
    do_something() {
     lock.lock();
     super.do_something();
     lock.unlock();
    }

and you can use your object seamlessly with other framework classes and method calls since its a vertex afterall.

Comment: Valid point and true. something which even i tried first. But this is an hard way of coding stuff to work according to the need. Found it to be problamatic in the long run as there is no particular policy one adheres to which in complete makes it a mess. Its tough to explain why it doesn't work. In short there is a lot to add up as just locking the vertex wont make it a usable framework. Edge's, read/write locks. Decisions about design,policies on how a vertex will behave if one requests it or how how a graph component should react upon lock on the component. in compelte tough to extend.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to create one big monitor.

```
public Object theBigGraphMonitor = new Object();
```

Before doing ANY operation on the graph, synchronize on that single monitor.

Fiddling with indivudial verticles seems to be hard to get right... To say the least.

Comment: Of course at that point you might as well use a single thread.

Comment: Perhaps a ReadWriteLock would speed up concurrent access, if there are relatively few changes to the graph.

Comment: Sorry but for the whole operation it will be blocked which is bad. I want a something like where to gain every vertex i will acquire a lock , so that when i am using it no one can change. similarly for paths.

Comment: @Jatin: If you really want locking on each vertex, then you must protect yourself against deadlocks. This in turn will affect the algorithms operating on the graph. I doubt that this can be done by a generic graph framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change nodes locally, you can maintain an individual lock for each node. The simplest way to do this would be to implement a custom node class with synchronized methods (you could use ReentrantLock as well) i.e. something like this:

```
public class SynchronizedNode extends Node {

    public synchronized void localOp1() { ... }

    public synchronized void localOp2() { ... }

}
```

or

```
public class SynchronizedNode extends Node {

    ReentrantLock lock ....;

    public synchronized void localOp1() { lock.lock() try { ... } finally { lock.unlock } }

    public synchronized void localOp2() { lock.lock() try { ... } finally { lock.unlock } }

}
```

Comment: Hi can you pl read the discussion with Ravi Bhatt below as on why this technique wont work

Comment: Ok, sorry about the repeated answer. However, after reading the conversation, it looks like you are unable to explain what you require clearly. It is very hard for anyone to provide answers to vague/unclear questions. Please provide a clearer explanation, failing which this question will have to be flagged/down voted (please see the first two questions in the FAQ about practical answerable questions).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [charts4j](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/) API. We are using it in our application with reasonable no of  concurrent users and there has been no problems yet. I am not sure if the API is thread safe or not.

One problem we have noticed is that the url of the graph generated will point to *http://www.google.com/...* which can be a problem if you are working inside a VPN and the internet is not available.(May be there is a way out it of it).